# C code is segfaulting while using fseek

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

I have a code that I thought I had compiled in the past and successfully but now I am running into a segfault and I cannot see why.

```
FILE *numbers = fopen("./e13.txt", "r");

//seeking the end of the file to get the correct size for the string
//I will store
fseek(numbers, 0, SEEK_END);
long fsize = ftell(numbers);
fseek(numbers, 0, SEEK_SET);

//Allocating memory to the string
char *string = malloc(fsize + 1);
```

I am trying to read a file into memory so I am getting the proper size of it and trying to `malloc` that amount of memory. I think it is segfaulting in the fseek function but I cannot see why...

Comment: Maybe it's time you started checking for errors.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Step 1. Read each man page to find out what values it returns on error. The [`fopen` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) for example. Step 2. Check for those errors. e.g. `if (!numbers) { perror("fopen failed"); exit(1); }`

Comment: @deltaskelta: By reading the manual!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fopen` can return `NULL` if it cannot open the file.  This is probably what is happening here.  You should check it like:

```
if(!numbers){/*report error and exit*/}
```

Also, if you simply want to get the size of a file, consider using `stat` if your system supports it.  If you also want to open it and read it all into memory, I would suggest using `mmap` if your system supports it:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int fd = open("e13.txt", O_RDONLY);
if(!fd){/*report error and exit*/}
size_t len;
{
    struct stat stat_buf;
    if(fstat(fd, &stat_buf)){
        close(fd);
        /*report error and exit*/
    }
    len = stat_buf.st_size;
}
void *map_addr = mmap(NULL, len, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
close(fd);
if(!map_addr){/*report error and exit*/}
/*do work*/
munmap(map_addr, len);
```